# How to Bind with a StringFormat

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `ComboBox` which I am binding to an `IEnumerable<int>` source.

The source has values like 12,13,14 but I want the `ComboBox` to display Version 12, Version 13, Version 14 etc with `SelectedValue` still 12, 13 and 14.

For now I am modifying the Source to add Version to it and then Binding the ComboBox to an IEnumerable.

**XAML**

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxVersions"  
              SelectedIndex="0" 
              SelectionChanged="ComboBoxVersions_OnSelectionChanged" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding EnvironmentVersions}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Version " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Since the `ItemTemplate` only defines how the items are displayed, the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` still holds the original value from your collection of version numbers.

Answer (score 5):

using ComboBox.ItemStringFormat:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EnvironmentVersions}" 
          ItemStringFormat="version: {0}" />
```

or using ComboBox.ItemTemplate

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat=Version: {0}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

or

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="Version " />
        <Run Text="{Binding }"/>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Only the `ItemStringFormat` works on an `IEnumerable<int>` list. The other two fail.

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like this

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat=Version: {0}}" />
```

Comment: The OP explicitly wants "with SelectedValue still 12, 3 and 14", which does not work with this solution.

Comment: @Marcin This doesn't work at all. I did give this a try but  it still shows items as 12, 13, 14

Comment: It's only an example of course. I've try to show you, how to use StringFormat with static text. and of course I've made a mistake. You should use it in your textblock.
I update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add a string format to the binding in the datatemplate.

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat=Version {0}}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Has no effect on an `IEnumerable<int>` because string format works with, well with the bindings to `string`s and not `int`s.